# Is usually tired, usually tired, and feels tired?

Tags: adverbs, auxiliary-verbs, sense-verbs

> - She is usually tired after coming back from school.
> - She usually tired after coming back from school.
> - She usually feels tired after coming back from school.

Which one is correct?

Also, are *usually*, *often*, and *seldom* nouns, adjectives, adverbs or other?

Comment: Hi Alice, and welcome to ELU. You might be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a good site for basic questions.

Comment: @medica Thanks for editing my question! It looks much more systematic now. :) How did you do that ? ELL= English Language Learners ?

Comment: Yes, ELL. Very nice (and good) site. I edited by clicking on the edit option under your question. If you want to see how the changes were made, click on the words above my avatar: *edited __ ago*. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are grammatical, and whilst the first and the last mean almost exactly the same thing, the middle one has a rather different meaning.

Between the first and the last there is little to choose. In the first one is describing her state of tiredness,  the last describes her feelings i.e of tiredness.

The middle case - *she usually tired after...school* - means, not that she necessarily comes home feeling tired, but at that point she would 'tire' (i.e become tired). In this instance one is using the past tense of the verb *tire*, whilst the other examples use the past participle.

As @Edwin Ashworth points out in a comment below - it helps if "tired" in this last instance is qualified by an adverb e.g. *she usually tired early* - though in my view the participle can work adequately on its own.

Comment: How about 'often' and 'always'? Are they the same as 'usually'? Are their sentence structure, usage and meaning the same ?

Comment: @Alice They work exactly the same as *usually* in this example. In fact it is exactly the same situation without any adverb at all. *she is tired when she comes home...* etc

Comment: The second actually cannot be claimed to be ungrammatical, but is unidiomatic without padding: Joan was finding the evening job hard. She usually tired quickly after coming back from school after a heavy day. The question is more suited to the ELL site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes you are right and I apologise to the OP. I hadn't spotted that 'tired'- the participle had been switched to 'tired'- the past tense.  I will amend my answer.

Comment: @WS2 Can I write this kind of sentences in a past tense ? Example: She was usually tired after coming back from school. Is this sentence grammatical ? Does it mean: she was usually tired after coming back from school in the past and now she isn't tired anymore after.. school?

Comment: @Alice Yes you seem to have grasped the idea thoroughly. *Before the doctors took a look at her she was usually tired after coming back from school, nowadays she is bouncing with energy and wanting to play with her friends.*